# Continuation of fonts in Debian distributions

Tags: fonts

Dear Wolfram Mathematica users at Debian-based distributions, if you have the newest distribution, can you verify that the fonts work? An Internet user who claims to maintain the fonts for Debian distributions has claimed (search for "kilobyte" on the page below)

https://blog.wolfram.com/2019/04/02/why-wolfram-tech-isnt-open-source-a-dozen-reasons/

that he will punish Mathematica for its not being open source software (and for 12 reasons they can crisply name) by orphaning the fonts that he was maintaining. Is a similar sabotage possible in Linux? If it is, can someone please make sure that the fonts don't disappear?

Answer (score -1):

This would be an extremely arrogant thing to say.
Debian has other categories: contrib and non-free, which fonts-mathematiuca has slotted into for some time.
People/organisations have valid reasons for not licencing their assets as totally free, and Mathematica hyave made these fonts available to Debian for years without charge.
I find it hard to believe any maintainer would say such a thing and, if he has, he has the right to not maintain a package as he sees fit, but obviously, it's not Mathematica he's punishing.
This is what makes me doubt it.
The whole episode, as presented, is puerile.